# Looking to develop an icon only application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am looking to develop a Cocoa application that will only have a icon at top menu. Not sure what this is officially called. This is very similar to the DropBox application. Any direction is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That icon is called a 'status item', and you can learn more about creating an application like this by reading up on the [`NSStatusItem` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [Status Bar Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/StatusBar.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000073i) document.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you. I was upvote and mark as answer once the site allows me to.